# Android 6 wlan wifi disconnects always

Tags: stock-android

Got a problem on my Galaxy Tab A since the upgrade to Android 6. The Wlan disconnects and reconn. always. It is not the routers fault or any other but most likely something in the software. Well I started searching through the different settings and changed this: 
"More connection settings" - "Nearby device scanning" and set this off. Now it seems to be fixed. I suppose this scanning disturbs the wifi frequencies or sth like this. Any other suggestions?

Thanks,

Hendish

Comment: "it is not a question for help, but I want to discuss this" › then it is off-topic here, sorry. This is not a forum to discuss things, but a Q&A site. I'd recommend you [edit] your question and remove that paragraph (otherwise your question gets closed as being off-topic) if you're interested in solutions – and move the discussion part to a forum.